# Could Not Load App error APK Android React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk, expo

So, I'm stuck with an error after generating APK with React-Native. I tried on multiple computers, 32-bit and 64-bit operating system and had no success.
How I got here

First, I created my app with

```
create-react-native-app suporteecontrole
```

Then I started developing my app, installing dependencies, and etc. After making sure that the APP was running without any errors, I ejected with the command line:

```
npm run eject
```

I've put my expo credentials and it worked without any errors too. I figured that it was going to work.
Generating APK's

To generate APK, i followed the instructions on this link:

[React Native Build Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

1 - I installed the JAVA 8 SDK, and all dependences too.
2 - I generated the Key by following the step one on the link.
3 - I changed all gradle files according to the link
4 - Then I runned this lines on cmd:

```
cd android
```

And

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

No errors popped up. I made it to the build successfully.

So, It generated some files: app-dev19-release.apk, app-dev-release.apk, app-devRemoteKernel-release.apk, app-prod-release.apk.

I installed app-prod-release.apk on my mobile, and returns an Expo error:
[Could not load app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0iLW.jpg)

photo_2018-07-24_12-57-51

I searched Google for this, and found nothing.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is frustrating how the create-react-native does expo by default instead of normal react app. But you've already ejected from the expo app, and your code now wont be working on it.

Instead you'll see a new app on your phone with the name and icon you chose. Try to find the App and run it. And to assemble a release, you actually need to sign it too, so I hope you've done the signing right. Take a look at this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html for signing if you face that error.

Comment: Yeah, This has been hard.
The image I uploaded is the error when I try to run it on my phone. 
About signing, I think I signed right. haha. I followed this link you gave me to make the build.

Comment: I think you're trying to run expo, but after eject, you cannot. Try to find your own app inside your launcher, because it must be installed and also bundled with your JS code.